# How to use Rust nom to get the last occurrence of a string?

Tags: rust, nom

I'm learning Rust as well as the nom crate. I have a string and it could be one of

```
* abc
* abc, test.txt
* abc, def, test.txt
* abc, test.txt, test.txt
```

I want to write a parser that gets the ending file name and all other parts as a tuple. So for the upper example inputs, the expected outputs are

```
* abc                      -> ("abc",           "")
* abc, test.txt            -> ("abc",           "test.txt")
* abc, def, test.txt       -> ("abc, def",      "test.txt")
* abc, test.txt, test.txt  -> ("abc, test.txt", "test.txt")
```

The following code is what I have right now.

```
fn test(input: &str) -> (String, String) {
    let result: IResult<&str, _, nom::error::Error<&str>> =
        all_consuming(
            many_till(
                is_a("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._,"),
                preceded(
                    tuple((space0, tag(","), space0)),
                    recognize(is_a("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._")),
                )))(input);

    result.map(|(_, x)| {
        println!("{:?}", x);
        return (x.0.join(""), x.1.to_string());
    }).unwrap_or_default()
}


#[test]
fn test1() {
    assert_eq!(test("test\\test2"), ("test\\test2".to_string(), "".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(test("test2\\a.txt, file1"), ("test2\\a.txt".to_string(), "file1".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(test("abc"), ("abc".to_string(), "".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(test("abc, test.txt"), ("abc".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(test("bc, def, test.txt"), ("abc, def".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(test("abc, test.txt, test.txt"), ("abc, test.txt".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string()));
}
```

When I run `cargo test`, I got the following error:

```
running 1 test
test test1 ... FAILED

failures:

---- test1 stdout ----
thread 'test1' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `("", "")`,
 right: `("test\\test2", "")`', src\main.rs:138:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    test1

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very roundabout way of getting your answer. Could you simply split at the last whitespace character (starting from the end)?

Comment: @GManNickG Yes I know I can use regex to get the result. Here I'm just using this as an example to learn nom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need `nom` to do that. You can just split the string on the last separator:

```rust
fn split_std(input: &str) -> (String, String) {
    match input.rfind(", ") {
        None => (input.to_owned(), "".to_owned()),
        Some(idx) => (input[..idx].to_owned(), input[idx + 2..].to_owned()),
    }
}
```

Doing it with nom is much more complex and slow. It will require parsing a `separated_list()`, then
joining the list elements and handling different corner cases and errors:

```rust
fn split_nom(input: &str) -> (String, String) {
    let result: IResult<_, _, nom::error::Error<_>> =
        nom::combinator::all_consuming(nom::multi::separated_list0(
            tag(", "),
            nom::bytes::complete::take_while(|ch| {
                nom::character::is_alphabetic(ch as u8)
                    || nom::character::is_digit(ch as u8)
                    || ch == '_'
                    || ch == '\\'
                    || ch == '.'
            }),
        ))(input);

    match result {
        Err(_) => (input.to_owned(), "".to_owned()),
        Ok((_, parts)) => {
            if parts.len() == 1 {
                return (parts[0].to_owned(), "".to_owned());
            }

            (
                parts[..parts.len() - 1].join(", "),
                parts[parts.len() - 1].to_owned(),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Tests:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::{split_nom, split_std};

    #[test]
    fn test_split_std() {
        verify(split_std);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_split_nom() {
        verify(split_nom);
    }

    fn verify(f: fn(&str) -> (String, String)) {
        assert_eq!(
            f("test\\test2"),
            ("test\\test2".to_string(), "".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(
            f("test2\\a.txt, file1"),
            ("test2\\a.txt".to_string(), "file1".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(f("abc"), ("abc".to_string(), "".to_string()));
        assert_eq!(
            f("abc, test.txt"),
            ("abc".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(
            f("abc, def, test.txt"),
            ("abc, def".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(
            f("abc, test.txt, test.txt"),
            ("abc, test.txt".to_string(), "test.txt".to_string())
        );
    }
}
```

PS: Your test cases does not match your code - for instance in the test cases you
have the `\` symbol, while it is not present in the accepted character list in your parser.